# how to scrape an aspx rendered page using python

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests, mechanize, scrapy

I am scraping an aspx rendered web page [Link to Page](http://www.tournamentsoftware.com/sport/draw.aspx?id=E880C7A5-0A60-4A98-8FF9-A3B7DD58F3E2&draw=4)

the  website is .aspx, i chose Selenium , mechanize , urllib , lxml , Beautiful soup , requests . any insights/recommendations on coding the next steps. Also used scrapy.

I have used requests :

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
request.get(url_to_page)
print request.content
```

it gives

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><meta charset="utf-8" /><title>
    www.tournamentsoftware.com
</title>
  <style>
    body {
      font: normal 12px/20px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
      color: #505050;
      background: #ccc url(//static.tournamentsoftware.com/images/cw_bg.png) repeat-x;
    }
    h2 {
      font: bold 16px/16px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif !important;
      color: #000;
      margin: 4px 0;
    }
    h4 {
      font: bold 13px/13px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif !important;
      margin: 0 0 -8px 0;
    }
    p {
      font: normal 12px/20px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
      margin: 12px 0;
    }
    p.note {
      font: normal 10px/10px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
      margin: 8px 0 0 0;
      text-align: center;
      color: #999;
    }
    p.note.error {
      font: bold 13px/20px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
      color: #f00;
    }

    .langtoggle { display:inline; margin-right:6px; }
    .langtoggle.active { display:none; }
    .langmessage { display:none; margin-bottom:20px; }
    .langmessage.active { display:block; }
    input.button {

      margin: 4px 0;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <form method="post" action="./default.aspx?returnurl=%2fsport%2fdraw.aspx%3fid%3dE880C7A5-0A60-4A98-8FF9-A3B7DD58F3E2%26draw%3d4" id="form1" class="lang1033">
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="p4eGoAC3005ctvGuhkv1w6Nanrs87p7iDcl4Hlk1SNw/cJovTDsJZeq54VdP4JR0injIJb59okjgeTpi30pz0LH9qjU=" />

<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR" id="__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR" value="A86F2231" />
    <div id="messagewindow">
      <p class="toggles"><a id="Lang1033" class="lang langtoggle active" href="#" onclick="switchLang(this)">English</a> </p><div id="divLang1033" class="langmessage active"><h2>The use of cookies on www.tournamentsoftware.com</h2><p>We are legally obliged to get your 
        elems = document.getElementsByClassName('langmessage');
        for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
          elems[i].className = 'langmessage';
        }
        document.getElementById(AThis.id).className = 'langtoggle active';
        document.getElementById('div' + AThis.id).className = 'langmessage active';
        return false;
      }
      function toggleCookiesHelp(AElmID) {
        document.getElementById(AElmID).style.display = 'block';
        return false;
      }
      function toggleCookiesHelpByClassName() {
        var elems = document.getElementsByClassName('removecookies');
        for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
          elems[i].style.display = 'block';
        }
        elems = document.getElementsByClassName('note');
        for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
          elems[i].className = 'note error';
        }
        return false;
      }
      if (storageAvailable()) {
        if (localStorage.getItem('cookiewall')) {
          toggleCookiesHelpByClassName();
        }
        var elems = document.getElementsByClassName('button');
        for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
          elems[i].addEventListener('click', function (e) {
            localStorage.setItem('cookiewall', '1');
          });
        }
      }
      function storageAvailable() {
        try {
          var x = '__storage_test__';
          localStorage.setItem(x, x);
          localStorage.removeItem(x);
          return true;
        } catch(e) {
          return false;
        }
      }
    </script>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Also tried with mechanize, scrapy. All of them are giving this result only. How to scrape those websites. But I am able to see the source code in the browser. Is there any way to scrape those data.

Comment: What is the issue? Have you tried using any of the library's mentioned above?

Comment: You need to include the doPostBack arguments in the post (__EVENTTARGET and __EVENTARGUMENT). Mechanize would be a good choice if it were more reliable, I would probably go with requests.

Comment: how to add _EVENTTARGET in request ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r_obj = requests.Session()

url = "http://www.tournamentsoftware.com/cookie/default.aspx?returnurl=%2fdefault.aspx"

fr_soup = r_obj.get(url)


soup = BeautifulSoup(fr_soup.content , "lxml")
#print soup

l = soup.find_all("input",type="hidden")
#print l

data = {
l[0]['name']:l[0]['value'],
l[1]['name']:l[1]['value'],
'btnAccept':'Yes, I accept'}

r_obj.post(url,verify=False,data=data)

url_needed = "http://www.tournamentsoftware.com/sport/draw.aspx?id=E880C7A5-0A60-4A98-8FF9-A3B7DD58F3E2&draw=4"

final = r_obj.get(url_needed)


#print final.content

soup1 = BeautifulSoup(final.content,"lxml")

detail_tab = soup1.find_all("table")
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to use a framework which runs the client-side code for you. headless-chrome is one such tool.